# why we needed forRoot() method in angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

what is the use of forRoot() method in angular.under ngModule we are using this for Root() method like RouterModule.forRoot(routes).Do we need use this forRoot() for all which are presented inside imports array

Comment: [What is the `forRoot()` method?](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-the-forroot-method).

Answer (score 0):

Anything placed in a module's `providers` array is going to become a singleton instance which is available throughout the application.  Some modules need to be used both by applications (which should create the singletons) and by inner non-application modules (which shouldn't create the singletons but still might need to depend on the declarations/exports which are not singletons).  The idea behind `forRoot` is it creates the singletons so you only want to use it once...in your "root" module.

Here is the definition from the current source:

```
  static forRoot(routes: Routes, config?: ExtraOptions): ModuleWithProviders<RouterModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: RouterModule,
      providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        provideRoutes(routes),
        {
          provide: ROUTER_FORROOT_GUARD,
          useFactory: provideForRootGuard,
          deps: [[Router, new Optional(), new SkipSelf()]]
        },
        {provide: ROUTER_CONFIGURATION, useValue: config ? config : {}},
        {
          provide: LocationStrategy,
          useFactory: provideLocationStrategy,
          deps: [
            PlatformLocation, [new Inject(APP_BASE_HREF), new Optional()], ROUTER_CONFIGURATION
          ]
        },
        {
          provide: RouterScroller,
          useFactory: createRouterScroller,
          deps: [Router, ViewportScroller, ROUTER_CONFIGURATION]
        },
        {
          provide: PreloadingStrategy,
          useExisting: config && config.preloadingStrategy ? config.preloadingStrategy :
                                                             NoPreloading
        },
        {provide: NgProbeToken, multi: true, useFactory: routerNgProbeToken},
        provideRouterInitializer(),
      ],
    };
  }
```

What it does is take `RouterModule` and extend it by adding a bunch of additional provided services.  These additional services should only be instantiated once in an application because they have state that needs to be shared across the entire application.